# Pass JSP Input with href link

Tags: arrays, jsp, parameter-passing, href

I want to pass input data with a href instead of a button. The problem is I am sending an array,  my for loop the input data is being stored so It creates multiple links. What is the course of action to take to fix this.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Firstjsp</title>
</head>
<body>
<% String locations[] = {"Loan 1", "33.890542", "151.274856", "Address 1","true", "-35404.34"};
for (int i =0; i<locations.length; i++)
{
%>
<form name="submitForm" method="POST" action="Mapper.jsp">
<Input type = "Hidden" name = "loc" value = "<%= locations[i] %>">
<A HREF="Mapper.jsp">View Map</A>
</form>

<%
}   
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In HTML, tags and attributes should be all lowercase. Don't capitalize them.

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP request query string takes the form of `name1=value1&name2=value2&name3=value3`. So all you need to do is converting the `String[]` to a `String` in exactly that format. Additional requirement is to use `URLEncoder` to encode the names and values so that any special characters are been converted to `%nn` format for proper usage in URLs.

This should do:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for (String location : locations) {
    if (builder.length() > 0) builder.append("&");
    builder.append("loc=").append(URLEncoder.encode(location, "UTF-8");
}

String locationsQuery = builder.toString();
```

Then you can specify it in the link as follows:

```
<a href="Mapper.jsp?<%=locationsQuery%>">View Map</a>
```

How to obtain it in the other side has already been answered in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266163/pass-array-jsp-to-jsp).

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, writing raw Java code in JSPs is [officially discouraged since a decade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202). You can achieve the same on a more easy manner with [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<c:url>`, `<c:param>` and `<c:forEach>`. Here's a kickoff example assuming that you've done a `request.setAttribute("locations", locations)` in your preprocessing servlet or in top of JSP:

```
<c:url value="Mapper.jsp" var="mapperURL">
  <c:forEach items="${locations}" var="loc">
    <c:param name="loc" value="${loc}" />
  </c:forEach>
</c:url>
<a href="${mapperURL}">View Map</a>
```